# ImageView and listview in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to put imageview and listview in two separate relative layouts, but when I am adding image to imageview the height of image is less as it should be, it is adding some black space between image and listview. but when I put textview it works fine. here is code snippets ..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bar" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list11"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
android:focusable="false"
android:listSelector="@color/itemcolor1"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:scrollingCache="false" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks guys, it is annoying

Comment: why 2 separate RelativeLayouts? What kind of layouts do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="10"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
       android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/actionbar_background"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list11"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
android:focusable="false"
android:layout_weight="8"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:scrollingCache="false" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for the answer, helped alot to fix it, but these answers need minor tweaking, so I am writing here for future reference for others

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
   android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bar" />

  <ListView
   android:id="@+id/list11"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:listSelector="@color/itemcolor1">
    </ListView>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting scale type of the image view:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bar" />

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list11"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
android:focusable="false"
android:listSelector="@color/itemcolor1"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:scrollingCache="false" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```